# How to get sorted queryset with multiple order by clause?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have records in my db which are submitted by different user. I want to query such that i get some of the records but sorted in the order of time they were submitted .

I am able to achieve this using this query.

```
records_id_list=[5,7,9,42,55,65,78,92,116,192,785]
query_object=Records.objects.filter(record_id__in=records_id_list).order_by('registration_time').reverse()
```

But i want to add another order by clause where  the records which is submitted by currently logged in user should appear first and then other users records(sorted only by registration_time)
" **submitted_by_id** " is the field name and i can access the current logged in user as userId

Any help if i can achieve this in the query?

Comment: You can pass multiple params into order by `order_by('first', 'second')`.. but I can't see where you define your logged in users.

Comment: i can access the current logged in user id as self.user.id in Django. There will be only one user

Answer (score 2):

You can do `Records.objects.filter(record_id__in=records_id_list).order_by('registration_time', 'submitted_by_id').reverse()`

Here is a link to the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by

Comment: I want to filter the records. and their order would be like records with user 1 in order of time and after this all the other records in order of time

Comment: @AmanGupta The idea is the same - just switch the 2 arguments being sent into order_by

Comment: but what if the current logged in user id is lets say 70, it will not give the current users samples at the top.   (i might be missung  the key concept here :hence just to clarify)